# PHP adding <Head> files into <Body>

Tags: php, html, templating

I'm pretty new to PHP, my main issue is, while running an local server with MAMP the site page works fine, but when hosted on a remote repo the entirety of header.php's contents get stuffed into the `<body>` and not `<head>`. My code is as follows:

```
  <?php
  $pageName = "This is my page title";
  $isHomeStyle = true;
  $mainjs = true; 
  $flexisel = false;
  $lazyload = false; 

  include("includes/header.php");
  include("includes/navbar.php");?>

<body>
...
</body>
```

When I load it on localhost, the head appears where it should be and everything works great, when I see it online, however, the code looks like this;

```
<head></head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar"></div>
    <title>This is my Page title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="project/css/home.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="project/css/styles.css" />

...

<body>
```

Obviously thats not right, what am I missing?

EDIT: The head.php file is as follows:

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Page Name | <?= $pageName ?></title>
    <? if (true == $isHomeStyle): ?>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="project/css/home.css" />
    <? endif; ?>
  </head>
```

**Issue Resolved** The issue was my use of shorthand  tags, apparently it's not fully supported everywhere. Thank you all!

Comment: should navbar be in the body?

Comment: Did you delete your cache?

Comment: Please show us the `header.php` file that produces that output. You may be misplacing some tags.

Comment: The header file belongs in `<head>` while navbar file belong in `<body>` and is what's called "HTML 101". That isn't what I'm seeing in your first piece of code.

Comment: @4castle I've updated the original post with the header.php file. Is my issue that I'm trying to load the doctype as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [PHP Pear Docs](https://pear.php.net/manual/en/standards.tags.php):

> Always use `<?php ?>` to delimit PHP code, not the `<? ?>` shorthand. This is required for PEAR compliance and is also the most portable way to include PHP code on differing operating systems and setups.

This is likely the reason that it works on localhost but not on your online repo.

Also, make sure to move the `include("includes/navbar.php");` down inside the `<body>` tag.

Comment: Thanks, this sounds like its the issue. I'm assuming this means variables like $pageName would be `<?php $pageName ?>` as well correct?

Comment: You're welcome :) It would actually be `<?php echo $pageName ?>`

Answer (score 2):

You aren't closing your `<head>` in the HTML. Some browsers (Chrome for sure) try to intelligently manipulate the DOM to fix syntactical HTML errors. In this case, I believe your browser is automatically placing the output from your includes straight into the body. Add a closing `</head>` tag before the opening `<body>` tag and you should be fine. Also, I'm pretty sure your `include("includes/navbar.php");` should be in the actual body.

Comment: I've moved the PHP into a head tag rather than having the head tags be closed inside the template, I also moved the navbar to the body. When loaded on the remote server now, the head shows up where it's supposed to be, but my PHP is treated as a comment. I'm assuming this is an issue with my installed version of PHP?

Comment: Can you elaborate? I'm not sure how that would be the case...Are you sure the server actually has PHP installed and running?

Comment: yeap, we've been using PHP on this server for over two years now, im just now attempting this templating change which is why I'm so thrown off. Basically, the template header.php has an if statement (see above) and it gets rendered in the browser as an html comment, even though the rest of the PHP works properly (ie including the navbar).

Comment: Send me a link to a pastebin or something where I can see the code

Comment: http://pastebin.com/RgQA0gp1 This is the code I had before I made the changes suggested by 4castle, I appreciate any other help. Honestly Im stumped and pretty sure this is a simple mistake.

Comment: Looks like the issue was using shorthand <? ?> tags and not echoing my variables properly. Like I said, rookie mistake, I appreciate the help!